# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, java-8, error404

tengo un problema con un proyecto que tengo, al iniciar el proyecto se cierrra y no se por que, tambien habia estado trabajando con inicar sesion con firebase, tambien con google y no se que pasa que de un momento a otro dejo de funcionar como lo estaba haciendo, pero cuando empece con eso comenzo con error:

````
    Process: com.example.offa, PID: 2624
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.offa/com.example.offa.ResgActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3620)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2183)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7617)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.offa.ResgActivity.onCreate(ResgActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7817)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7806)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1328)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3452)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3620) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2183) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7617) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)```




Espero que me puedan ayudar, por que no entiendo por que el error :( gracias :D esto me ayudaria con un proyecto de la escuela, es algo importante y me seria de mucha ayuda par apoder salir adelante jsjsjs ayudenme porfavor
````

Comment: Hola. Aprende a depurar tu código. El mensaje de error te está diciendo que intentas un `setOnClickListener` en un `TextView` que es nulo. Revisa pues el código y si no encuentras el error, pulsa en [edit] y agrégalo a la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Al iniciar el proyecto se cierra y te da errores de Android? ¿No querrás decir *al iniciar la aplicación en el dispositivo, automáticamente se cierra y da ese error*?